# MySQL: Get common records by user ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to think this is a relatively easy query but I'm stumped. I've got an achievements table, a users table, and a users_achievements table. I want to determine what achievements more than one user share in common based on what exists in the users_achievements table.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.description, a.badge_path, b.earned_on 
FROM achievements AS a 
LEFT JOIN users_achievements AS b ON a.id=b.achievements_id 
WHERE b.users_id=1 
  AND b.users_id=2
```

This returns no results even though the users with ids 1 and 2 share two common records from the users_achievements table based on the achievements_id (so 4 records total--one for each user for each achievement_id). If I use "OR" or "IN" I get records, but that's not inclusive of BOTH ids, just either...I need the query to qualify both IDs.

Comment: `WHERE b.users_id=1 AND b.users_id=2` - this can never possibly be true.

Comment: Yes, I realize that...was psuedo sql in an attempt to show what I was trying to do...should have noted that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.description, a.badge_path, ua.earned_on
FROM achievements a JOIN
     users_achievements ua
    ON a.id = ua.achievements_id
WHERE ua.users_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.description, a.badge_path, ua.earned_on
HAVING count(distinct ua.users_id) = 2;
```

Note the following:

- The table aliases a abbreviations.  This makes the query easier to read.
- The `left join` should be unnecessary.  With such a table structure, the foreign key relationships should match.
- The `WHERE` clause filters for just the two users.
- The `HAVING` clause guarantees that both are present in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.description, a.badge_path, b.earned_on, c.earned_on 
FROM achievements AS a 
    JOIN users_achievements AS b ON a.id = b.achievements_id 
    JOIN users_achievements AS c ON a.id = c.achievements_id 
WHERE b.users_id=1 AND c.users_id=2
```

Here you are selecting what achievements users 1 & 2 have earned in common and when.

Comment: Selected Gordon's answer but this seems to work well too. Upvoted. Thanks.